# changing one char in a c string

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to understand why the following code is illegal:

```
int main ()
{
    char *c = "hello";
    c[3] = 'g'; // segmentation fault here
    return 0;
}
```

What is the compiler doing when it encounters `char *c = "hello";`?

The way I understand it, its an automatic array of char, and `c` is a pointer to the first char. If so, `c[3]` is like `*(c + 3)` and I should be able to make the assignment.

Just trying to understand the way the compiler works.

Comment: **arrays are not pointers** and **pointers are not arrays**. The string literal (`"hello"`) is an array of 6 characters (count the null terminator). Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/). Once you've done that, read the other sections too :)

Comment: Duplicate of too many to list here.

Comment: We need to introduce a filter in the SO ask question code that detects `char *XX = "..."` and provides the answer there and then, inline in the ask question dialog.

Answer (score 12):

String constants are immutable. You cannot change them, even if you assign them to a `char *` (so assign them to a `const char *` so you don't forget).

To go into some more detail, your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
int main() {
  static const char ___internal_string[] = "hello";
  char *c = (char *)___internal_string;
  c[3] = 'g';
  return 0;
}
```

This `___internal_string` is often allocated to a read-only data segment - any attempt to change the data there results in a crash (strictly speaking, other results can happen as well - this is an example of 'undefined behavior'). Due to historical reasons, however, the compiler lets you assign to a `char *`, giving you the false impression that you can modify it.

Note that if you did this, it would work:

```
char c[] = "hello";
c[3] = 'g'; // ok
```

This is because we're initializing a non-const character array. Although the syntax looks similar, it is treated differently by the compiler.

Comment: +1 for *roughly* ... but in C, a string literal type is not `const char[N]` (with `N` just large enough). String literals really have type `char[N]` but changing them is undefined.

Comment: I did say _roughly_ equivalent :)

Answer (score 9):

there's a difference between these:

```
char c[] = "hello";
```

and

```
char *c = "hello";
```

In the first case the compiler allocates space on the stack for 6 bytes (i.e. 5 bytes for "hello" and one for the null-terminator.

In the second case the compiler generates a static const string called "hello" in a global area (aka a *string literal*, and allocates a pointer on the stack that is initialized to point to that const string.

You cannot modify a const string, and that's why you're getting a segfault.

Comment: In C, a string literal type is not `const char[N]` (with `N` just large enough). String literals really have type `char[N]` but changing them is undefined.

Comment: You not recived a correct, because not is a solution about your answer. He want change specific character, no change to other structure, and yes is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the contents of a string literal. You need to make a copy.

```
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char *c = strdup("hello");  // Make a copy of "hello"
    c[3] = 'g';
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that using `char c[]` as suggested by the other posters makes it less error prone, since you don't need to free anything.