# in my code ,second printf is not printing any value

Tags: c

My code is compiled fine but the second **printf** of my code is not printing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * const p="pointerconstant";

    printf("%s",p);

    *p='B';

    printf("\n%s",p);
}
```

When I run the following program, it outputs..

```
pointerconstant
pointerconstant
```

But it should be..

```
pointerconstant
Bointerconstant
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? The answer depends very much on that, since they differ in a case like this. And in the future, please only tag the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: The problem is that your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why do you claim that the second `printf` doesn't print anything when your output example shows clearly that it does?

Comment: as @molbdnilo has already pointed out,  your code has undefined behavior. A live test of your code is here: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/LMbwgWoOs44NJmj6,  feel free to use it to diagnose memory issues in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
*p='B';
```

You're trying to modify the first byte of the char array that the pointer points to. This doesn't work because that's a read-only part of your program's binary. Fix it by copying it to the stack or heap:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char * const p = strdup("pointerconstant"); // string is copied to the heap
    printf("first=%s", p);
    *p = 'B';
    printf("\nsecond=%s", p);
    free(p); // copy of the string on the heap is released again
    return 0; // 0 indicates that the program executed without errors
}
```

The result is:

> first=pointerconstant
>
> second=Bointerconstant

On a side note, in my opinion it would be more idiomatic to write `*p = 'B';` as `p[0] = 'B';`, but that's up to you, of course.

---

Note: this answer is in C, the question is also tagged as C++

Answer (score 3):

i think your issue is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7547849/5809736

From  @bdonlan for your code:
Note that if you did this, it would work:

```
    char p[] = "pointerconstant";
    printf("first=%s",p);
    *p='B';
    printf("\nsecond=%s",p);
```

This is because we're initializing a non-const character array. Although the syntax looks similar, it is treated differently by the compiler.

Comment: you are answering about string constant ,my question was about of pointer constant

Comment: you could use in the same example a pointer constant without problem like this: 
    `char p[] = "pointerconstant"
    char * const a = p;
    printf("first=%s",a);
    *p='B';
    printf("\nsecond=%s",a);`

you cannot change the pointer's value, but you can change the value of the array.